# ¿Por que Chrome me manda un error 404, pero Opera me abre la página?

Tags: php, wordpress

No entiendo realmente que sucede, pero es muy raro.
Subí una página a un hosting, y estoy probándola, 
Es en wordpress, con algunas páginas que no son de Wordpress.
Todo esto está probado en localhost, pero en el servidor, hay comportamientos extraños.

Ahora mismo, si ingreso a la dirección: http://bowa.cl/bowa/loginConsumos.php

Desde Opera, obtengo una página de login (la correcta) con algunos temas de css que resolver aún.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mientras tanto, desde Chrome, me está mandando a una página de 404 de wordpress...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece ser un problema de cache, en tu navegador de chrome, presiona f12, luego dirígete al botón de refrescar que esta en la parte superior izquierda del navegador, presiona click izquierdo y selecciona Vaciar cache y volver a cargar de forma forzada.

Esto reiniciara la cache de tu sitio.

Comment: Se puede hacer lo mismo con **control f5**, asi se recarga la pagina sin cache, es lo mismo ¿no?

Comment: @Davidflogar no estoy seguro si varia el sistema y versión o bien por el tipo de teclado, en mi caso es Shift f5 no control

Comment: No, no es lo mismo con el F5, eso ya lo habia probado. Y gracias @jefferzzon

Comment: Ok gracias @JefferzonBol solo quería saber si los dos tenían el mismo efecto :)